# unable to install php 7.3 on ubuntu 20

Tags: php, ubuntu

hi i want to install php `7.3` on ubuntu `20` for my nginx web server, when i try to install the `7.4` version every thing is fine but for `7.3` i get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
```

then i run the commands below :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3
```

but again it shows that it cant locate the package . does ubuntu 20 supports php `7.3` or below and if yes what can be wrong with mine ??

Comment: I have the same problem exactly as you.

Comment: This is not a programming question, even though you're trying to install a programming language. Please take this to e.g. askubuntu.com.

Comment: Here is the issue in Askubuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231381/unable-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Add Ondrej PPA repository to your system.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Install php7.3 and check it's installed.

```
sudo apt install -y php7.3
php -v
```

This also works for php 7.4, php7.2 and php5.6. Just change the relevant digits.